# Code executes without aparent reason

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm doing a small program where the user selects which option wants to do. I do it using switch, and everything works fine, but now I'm trying to add the ability to choose language, I'm trying to accomplish this using arrays (I don't know how to explain it properly, but it's easy to see in the code).

```
//Each menu option
static String[][] menuOptions =
{
    {
        "1. Check your grades",
        "2. Check if you can examine for a driving license",
        "3. Check if a number is odd or even",
        "4. Check if a number is divisible by 7",
        "5. Check if a triangle is equilater",
        "6. Check who won",
        "7. Check which number is bigger",
        "8. Check if you can have a \"Carnet Jove\"",
        "9. Convert numeric grades to letters",
        "10. Exit Application"
    },
    {
        "1. Comprobar si has aprobado",
        "2. Check if you can examine for a driving license",
        "3. Check if a number is odd or even",
        "4. Check if a number is divisible by 7",
        "5. Check if a triangle is equilater",
        "6. Check who won",
        "7. Check which number is bigger",
        "8. Check if you can have a \"Carnet Jove\"",
        "9. Convert numeric grades to letters",
        "10. Exit Application"
    }
};
//End of Options

static Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

static boolean correctInput = false;
static int language;
static int selection;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("\t1. English\t2. Español\n");
    System.out.print("Select a Language:\tSeleccione un Idioma:\t");
    language = Scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("");
    while (correctInput != true)
    {
        menu(language);
        try //Comprobamos que el usuario haya introducido un numero
        {
            selection = Integer.parseInt(Scan.nextLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) //En caso de error lo gestionamos
        {
            //No hacemos nada
        }

        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1:
                correctInput = true;
                checkGrades();
                break;
            case 2:
                correctInput = true;
                chechDrivingLicense();
                break;
            case 3:
                correctInput = true;
                checkOddNum();
                break;
            case 4:
                correctInput = true;
                checkDivBy7();
                break;
            case 5:
                correctInput = true;
                checkEquilater();
                break;
            case 6:
                correctInput = true;
                checkWinner();
                break;
            case 7:
                correctInput = true;
                checkBigger();
                break;
            case 8:
                correctInput = true;
                checkCarnetJove();
                break;
            case 9:
                correctInput = true;
                convertNumGradeToLetter();
                break;
            case 10:
                correctInput = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\nInput not valid. Please enter"
                        + " a valid number\n");
        }
    }

}

private static void menu(int language)
{
    System.out.println("\n");
    int sel = 12;
    for (String s : menuOptions[language - 1])
    {
        System.out.println("\t" + s);
    }
    System.out.print("\nSelect an option: \t");

}
```

Instead of displaying the selected menu (that for now only has one option translated, but is enough to check if it works or not), what's happening is that once the menu is displayed, it automatically selects an option (which is always an invalid one) and triggers the repetition of the menu 1 time. It's not a big nuisance but I wanna fix it.

Here's a what the current output looks like:
[image]

Comment: best ... title ... ever ... usually it executes because you run it :) tried setting a different value in the catch block?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, i've tried setting a value for _selection_ in the catch block. It didn't change the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
language = Scan.nextInt();
```

This reads an integer, but not the following newline.

```
selection = Integer.parseInt(Scan.nextLine());
```

The first time this is reached there's a newline waiting to be read. `nextLine()` immediately returns an empty string.

```
catch (NumberFormatException ex) //En caso de error lo gestionamos
{
    //No hacemos nada
}
```

You might see this if you didn't swallow the resulting exception. Don't handle exceptions by doing nothing! At least call `ex.printStackTrace()` to see the error message. Better yet, ask the user to try again.

To fix your program, avoid mixing `nextInt()` and `nextLine()`. It's better to always use `nextLine()`. Read `language` the same way you do `selection` and you'll be better off.

```
language = Integer.parseInt(Scan.nextLine());
```